# Can't seem to get containers aligned properly even though I am using flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox, jsx

```
import "./portfolio.scss"


export default function portfolio() {
    return (
        <div className="portfolio" id="portfolio">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                <li className="active">Featured</li>
                <li>Web app</li>
                <li>Mobile app</li>
                <li>Design</li>
                <li>Branding</li>
            </ul>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="item">
                    <img
                    src="assets/default-product-image.png" 
                    alt="" />
                    <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                <div className="item">
                    <img
                    src="assets/default-product-image.png" 
                    alt=""/>
                    <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                <div className="item">
                    <img
                    src="assets/default-product-image.png" 
                    alt=""/>
                    <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
                </div>
                
        </div> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
    )
}
```

This is my .jsx I am making div's with containers in them and the containers seem to not be aligned properly, see the picture below.
I am trying to get them all aligned with even margin but the third one seems to be off, when i change the device on which i view it tho they align perfectly below each other.

and this is my scss

```
@import "../../global.scss";

.portfolio{
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    h1{
        font-style: 500px;
    }

    ul{
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;

        li{
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-right: 9px;
            padding: 7px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;

            &.active{
                background-color: $mainColor;
                color: white;
            }
        }

    }

    .container{
        width: 70%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        

        .item{
            width: 220px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(240, 234, 234);
            margin: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: white;
           position: relative;

            h3{
                position: absolute;
                font-style: 20px;
            }
            img{
                width: 100%;    
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            &:hover{
                background-color: $mainColor;
                img{
                    opacity: 0;
                    z-index: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like right now I want the items to be evenly spread apart.

[image]

Comment: I haven't looked at your CSS, but the html seems very off. You're nesting the containers like russian dolls, that cannot be on purpose. Fix your indentation and the problem should appear clear as day (look at all the `</div>`s).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the `<div class='container'>`s nested is probably what is causing misalignment. I don't see any images in your question, but I'm willing to bet your code is producing containers that get smaller and smaller the further down the tree it gets, which is exaggerated on small screens.

Start by closing your container divs before opening another. Also, use consistent indentation - that will help make this issue more obvious when you're reading your code. I have cleaned up your code and changed nothing except the HTML markup. The top example in the linked pen has cleaned up markup, while the bottom example has the containers grouped.

https://codepen.io/the_Northway/pen/QWqapbg?editors=1100

```css
.portfolio {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.portfolio#portfolio_fixed {
  background-color: orange;
}
.portfolio h1 {
  font-style: 500px;
}
.portfolio ul {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.portfolio ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 9px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio ul li.active {
  background-color: #445566;
  color: white;
}
.portfolio .container {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.portfolio .container .item {
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f0eaea;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio .container .item h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-style: 20px;
}
.portfolio .container .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
.portfolio .container .item:hover {
  background-color: #445566;
}
.portfolio .container .item:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio" id="portfolio_fixed">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">Featured</li>
        <li>Web app</li>
        <li>Mobile app</li>
        <li>Design</li>
        <li>Branding</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt="" />
            <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt=""/>
            <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt=""/>
            <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="portfolio" id="portfolio_broken">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">Featured</li>
        <li>Web app</li>
        <li>Mobile app</li>
        <li>Design</li>
        <li>Branding</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt="" />
            <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt=""/>
                <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/default-product-image.png" alt=""/>
                    <h3>Coming soon</h3> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```